# Ошибка при вызове метода add() класса Vector java

Tags: java, vector

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestProg {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        Vector v = new Vector();
        v.add(new Integer(20));
    }
}
```

При вызове метода add() выходит след ошибка :

> C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\ProgramJava>javac TestProg.java
>   Note: TestProg.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
>   Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

помогите разобраться pls , пишу в notepad в netbeans работает нормально, версия java 1.8

Comment: На дворе 2015й год, зачем вообще использовать древний `Vector` да еще и под Java 8?

Answer (score 3):

Укажите в javac:

```
javac -Xlint:unchecked
```

Можно еще указать тип:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector<Integer> v = new Vector<Integer>();
        v.add(20);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Это не ошибка, а предупреждение. Несмотря на это сообщение программа нормально компилируется и работает. Предупреждение связано с тем, что вы не указали generic-параметр для типа `Vector`. Исправить можно так:

```
Vector<Integer> v = new Vector<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

можно также аннотировать метод: @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Answer (score -1):

Можно юзать List.
Из него можно массив получить.
Например:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
list.add(3);
Integer[] arr = list.toArray(new Integer[list.size()]);
```

Как альтернатива вектору.